# why is my curl request not working what i´m i doing wrong

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, curl, php-curl

What am I doing wrong?

I'm trying to make a new curl requestfrom a drop down list what im i doing wrong?

```
<form action="" method="POST">
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comment">Select Page:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="pagecall" id="pagecall" style="width:75%;float:right;" onchange="davsele(this.value);">
            <?php
                $totalPage = $dataget['total'] / 20;
                for($i=1;$i<=$totalPage;$i++)
                {
                    $selc = ($getPageCount==$i)?'selected':'';
                    echo "<option value=".$i." $selc>Page No. ".$i."</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

The function i trying to call

```
<?php

    function proCall() {

    $ch = curl_init();

    $getPageCount == sval;

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://products-export-api.g2a.com/v1/products?page=$getPageCount");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $server_output = curl_exec($ch);

        //Gets the API data
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    //curl_close($curl);
    $dataget = json_decode($response,true);
    print_r($dataget);
    echo "test";
    curl_close ($ch);
    }
?>
```

what is being sent from dropdown to js function

```
function davsele(sval)
{

var result = "<?php proCall();?>";
alert(result);
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up Javascript and PHP in a way, that does not work. You try to access the JS-Variable (sval) in a PHP-Function, which wont work.

You need to call the PHP-Function on the Server with a AJAX-Request and pass the JS-Variable as GET-Parameter.

Therefor you should put your PHP-Code in a File (for example api.php) and call it in your JS-Function:

```
function davsele(sval) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      alert(this.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "api.php?value=" + sval, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

The content of the api.php could look like this:

```
<?php
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://products-export-api.g2a.com/v1/products?page=' . $_GET['value']);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $server_output = curl_exec($curl);

    //Gets the API data
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    //curl_close($curl);
    $dataget = json_decode($response,true);
    print_r($dataget);
    echo "test";
    curl_close ($curl);
?>
```

Comment: thanks, I tried that but nothing happens after i make a new selection from drop down.

Comment: do you see any errors in the javascript console (open with F12)?

Comment: GET https://www.nerdsbelike.com/woo/wp-admin/api.php?value=6 404
davsele @ admin.php?page=woocommerce_g2a:914
onchange @ admin.php?page=woocommerce_g2a:474
ListPicker._handleMouseUp

Comment: Did you upload the api.php file to the folder "wp-admin" on your server? Probably you should put the api.php file in the domain root directory and change the call in the js function to 
xhttp.open("GET", "/api.php?value=" + sval, true);

Comment: No i put it in /woo/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-g2a/assets

Ok I will try that, but I don't think it's good practice from what I heard from wordpress developers.

Comment: you can put the api.php whereever you want, but you have to make sure, to have the correct path in the AJAX-Request.